# How do I get a variable of the number of times a button has been clicked, store it online and then access it later?

Tags: javascript, file, variables, button, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to have a button that can be clicked and will then display the number of times it has been clicked. I want the variable, let's call it x, to be stored online, so that if one person clicks the button 5 times and then another person later clicks it an additional 3 times each screen will then display x as 8. I attempted local storage but that only stores the variable on the browser. I have been doing some research and it seems like I will have to store x on a file and then access it with an XMLHttpRequest. I am very new at Javascript and am not sure how to do this. Could someone please respond with code that would achieve this and an explanation of what I will have to do to store the variable?

Comment: store it on a server.use server side language like php for that.you can use file system or a database to store clicked amount.

Comment: You need to do work both in server and client for this purpose. The easy part is for each click that is issued you should post it to the server and then the server persist this click to a database, a file in your file system whatever.   Then you should for each client you have to subscribe to a publisher whose purpose would be to publish the change of `x` to the subscribed clients. Apparently, in your case you should keep in mind that some clicks may be not persisted at all due to failure in the post events, you should think about this to find a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

For the Javascript side of it, you can use jQuery to make things a little easier

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

 /* perform AJAX XMLHttpRequest */
  $.get("/click_count.php", function(data) {

   /* write the response into the HTML document */
    $("#click_count").text(data);
  });
});

function save_click() {

   /* perform AJAX XMLHttpRequest */
  $.post("/save_click.php", function(data) {

    /* write the result to the HTML document */
    $("#click_count").text(data);
  });
}
```

```html
 <!--  include jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<body>

  <button onClick="save_click();">click me!</button>

  Button has been clicked: <span id="click_count">0</span> times!
</body>

</html>
```

Finally, you need to have two files (or one that does two things) which take advantage of a server-side technology.

The way the Server-side code works is like this:

The clicks are stored in a file called **click_count.data**

whenever anybody visits the file  **click_count.php** , it simply reads the **click_count.data** file and sends whatevers in it as the response.

Then, there's another file called  **save_click.php**, which takes whatever is in **click_count.data** and then increases it by one before sending it back.

The Javascript AJAX requests use these two files to save data on the server rather than on a per-client basis.

For server-side, I've chosen to use PHP

File:  **click_count.php**

```
 <?php 

    /* print out the contents of the file 'click_count.data' */
    print_r(file_get_contents("click_count.data"));
  ?>
```

---

File:  **save_click.php**

```
 <?php  

   /* grab the current click count from click_count.data */
   $click_count = intval(file_get_contents("click_count.data"));

   /* increase it by 1 */
   $click_count++;

   /* write the new value into the file */
   file_put_contents("click_count.data", $click_count);

   /* print out new click count */
   print_r($click_count);

?>
```

---

Last file:  **click_count.data**

```
 0
```

---

Comment: This seems really helpful, but the .php files are not running and are instead just showing the code. suggestions?

Comment: here are the links to the pages:                                                                   http://www2.gsu.edu/~phltso/Answer_counter.html ***** http://www2.gsu.edu/~phltso/click_count.php *****       http://www2.gsu.edu/~phltso/save_click.php ***** http://www2.gsu.edu/~phltso/click_count.data

Comment: You have to have PHP enabled on your web server

Comment: You might need to contact the person in charge of ww2.gsu.edu and ask them if they can enable php for your account.
 
The alternative is to host the page yourself which is probably the way to go -- but its off topic as im sure you can find some information online about how to host your own web page from your computer

Comment: Thank you. this has been really helpful.